# sh boolean short circuit variable assignment

Tags: bash, sh, variable-assignment, short-circuiting

I'm trying to write a script that takes flags as parameters, so I want to be able to handle them being passed in any order.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh    

numargs=$#
echo $numargs

check_param () {
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

S=0
T=0
for ((i=1 ; i <= numargs ; i++)); do
    S=$S || check_param $1 "-s"
    T=$T || check_param $1 "-t"
    shift
done

echo "$S"
echo "$T"
```

however even though the function is returning 1 when the parameters are set, the variable / short circuit assignment doesn't seem to work.

```
$ ./script.sh aa ddd fff -s rrr
5
0
0
$ ./script.sh aa ddd fff -s rrr -t
6
0
0
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? `S=$S` will always replace the value of `S` by the value of `S`, so in other words, will not perform anything useful; moreover, this action always succeeds (unless `S` is marked read only), so the `check_param` after the `||` never gets executed. What were you expecting?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I was trying to use short circuit evaluation. In python I'd do `s = s or func(arg1, "-s")`. So that if `s` was already truthy, it would stay truthy, if it was falsey it would run the func and set the value to that. The idea is that if the flag is set anywhere in the args, by the end of the for loop it would be true

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works in shell scripts, though you could have something equivalent in Bash; but since your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, that's not available. Besides, it's useless; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh    

S=0
T=0

numargs=$#
printf "You passed %s arguments\n" "$numargs"

check_param () {
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$numargs" ]; do
   current_arg=$1
   shift
   case $current_arg in
      (-s)
         S=1 ;;
      (-t)
         T=1 ;;
      (*)
         set -- "$@" "$current_arg" ;;
   esac
   i=$((i+1))
done

printf "S flag: %s\n" "$S"
printf "T flag: %s\n" "$T"

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   printf "No arguments left.\n"
else
   printf "Arguments left (%s):\n" "$#"
   printf "   %s\n" "$@"
fi
```

I called this script `banana`, `chmod +x banana` and:

```
$ ./banana
You passed 0 arguments
S flag: 0
T flag: 0
No arguments left.
$ ./banana one two -s three
You passed 4 arguments
S flag: 1
T flag: 0
Arguments left (3):
   one
   two
   three
```

This will tell you whether an `-s` or `-t` option is given, and will leave the arguments on the arguments stack!